# removing unneeded query from generated url string in php

Tags: php, split

I have the following string generating mp3 urls for a music player on my site.

```
<?php echo $song->getTitle() ?>
```

which results in **/public/music_song/df/74/746b_2112.mp3?c=ec1e**

I would like to remove the query from the string 
resulting in **/public/music_song/df/74/746b_2112.mp3**

I've looked into how to split the url, but I'm nowhere near being a php genius just yet so I dont know weather to split or use preg_replace or how the heck to incorporate it into my existing string.

I have to get rid of these queries, they are unneeded and crashing my databases on a daily basis.

Comment: If such a thing is crashing your database, you have a much larger problem!

Comment: I'm sorry, the queries themselves aren't crashing the databases themselves but they are more or less contributing to a high server load. I'm currently running AMD x8, 1tb, raid 1, 16 cores @2.0ghz. I just optimized tables and brought load from 3.1 to 1.5. So things are getting better. Thx Tibor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$parsedInput = parse_url('/public/music_song/df/74/746b_2112.mp3?c=ec1e');
echo $parsedInput['path'];
// Results in /public/music_song/df/74/746b_2112.mp3
```

Edit: Since I havent worked with SocialEngine, Im guessing that what you need to do is:

```
<?php $parsed = parse_url($song->getFilePath());
      echo $this->htmlLink($parsed['path'], 
                           $this->string()->truncate($song->getTitle(), 50), 
                           array('class' => 'music_player_tracks_url', 
                                 'type' => 'audio', 
                                 'rel' => $song->song_id )); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Pratt! I will give this solution a shot

Comment: Pratt, do you mind helping me re-write my function... I've tried a few times and keep getting errors. Here is my code as it is used now. `<?php echo $this->htmlLink($song->getFilePath(),
              $this->string()->truncate($song->getTitle(), 50),
              array(
                'class' => 'music_player_tracks_url',
                'type' => 'audio',
                'rel' => $song->song_id
            )) ?>`

Comment: Pratt, thank you for your help! Your solution worked wonderfully! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
list($keep) = explode('?', '/public/music_song/df/74/746b_2112.mp3?c=ec1e');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just realize I provided the wrong information. I am using "<?php echo $this->htmlLink($song->getFilePath(),
              $this->string()->truncate($song->getTitle(), 50),
              array(
                'class' => 'music_player_tracks_url',
                'type' => 'audio',
                'rel' => $song->song_id
            )) ?>" and need to apply the explode to the string that generates my url ie "$this->htmlLink($song->getFilePath()".

Comment: I'm *guessing* that you'll want to place `$song->getFilePath()` in the  `explode()` function for this to work.

Comment: I apologize, I am a self proclaimed novice. I am still learning.

Comment: Yes Jon, That is exactly what I need.

Comment: unfortunately `$song->getFilePath()` doesn't get the url by itself, it has to have `$this->htmlLink($song->getFilePath()`. If you can point me in the right direction it would be an enormous help.

Comment: John, here is what I'm thinking. `$this->htmlLink explode('?', '$song->getFilePath')` am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would say try to print out the file path any way you until you get what you'rte looking for. Then plug it into `explode()`. I'm not sure how your code works exactly so I can't be sure where that value is hiding or how to get at it.

Comment: Thank you so much John, I'm going to continue to work on it. Hopefully I dont blow something up,lol! kind regards,